# Hide/Show Element when Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

I needed help on how to hide the second level ul & li and only display it if the 1st level li is clicked. For some reason, I can not find the document to add an onclick() function on the html part. Is this possible? Looking for js and css to get it work. Thanks in advance.

*So, by default, the list should look like this:*

Abgasanlage

Steuerkettenantrieb

*When Abgasanlage is clicked, its subcategory will open which should look like this:*

Abgasanlage

- Sensoren

Steuerkettenantrieb

*When Steuerkettenantrieb is clicked, its subcategory will open which should look like this:*

Abgasanlage

Steuerkettenantrieb

- Steuerkettensätze
- Steuerketten
- Gleitschienen
- Kettendeckel
- Ritzel

Here's the html code:

```
<ul class="sidebar_cate">
    <li class="grid__item lvl-1  active">
        <a href="/collections/abgasanlage" class="site-nav lvl-1">Abgasanlage</a>
            <ul class="subLinks">
                <li class="lvl-2">
                    <a href="/collections/sensoren" class="site-nav lvl-2">Sensoren</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="grid__item lvl-1 ">
        <a href="/collections/steuerket-tenantrieb" class="site-nav lvl-1">Steuerkettenantrieb</a>
            <ul class="subLinks">
                <li class="lvl-2">
                    <a href="/collections/steuerkettensatze" class="site-nav lvl-2">Steuerkettensätze</a></li>
                <li class="lvl-2">
                    <a href="/collections/steuerketten" class="site-nav lvl-2">Steuerketten</a></li>
                <li class="lvl-2">
                    <a href="/collections/gleitschienen" class="site-nav lvl-2">Gleitschienen</a></li>
                <li class="lvl-2">
                    <a href="/collections/kettendeckel-und-kettenrader-ritzel" class="site-nav lvl-2">Kettendeckel</a></li>
                <li class="lvl-2">
                    <a href="/collections/ritzel" class="site-nav lvl-2">Ritzel</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So what you are saying, is that you would like to know how to add an event listener with javascript that will do something when there is a click event? Have a read of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event this will show you how to add a click event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done together with Js and CSS.

First give a class `subLinks` to inner UL. then hide it with CSS.

```
ul li > .subLinks {
    display: none
}
```

then write a click event on each li, check if inner `sublinks` exist then add `active` class to the `li` element. based on the `active` class show the inner list with css.

JS

```
$("#nested-list li").click(function(e) {
    if ( $(this).children("ul").length ) {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
ul li.active > .subLinks {
    display: block
}
```

see the example I have created. https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-ul-li-list-toggle-basic
This is a basic example to show how you can achieve it, you can further customize it to your needs and add more check to prevent clicking on the link etc.

Comment: I got it fixed with your help. Thanks a lot. The only problem is the parent UL would reload the page. 

This is what the file looks like: 

<ul class="sidebar_cate nested-collapsable-list" id="nested-list" >{% for link in linklists[block.settings.side_categories].links %}{% include 'mm-links' %}{% endfor %}</ul>

Do you know how I can insert javascript:void(0) to simply open the subcategories instead of the page refreshing on its own? Thanks again!

Comment: `preventDefault()` method of Event can help you with this. Inside the click event function use this `e.preventDefault();`. I have updated the example code also. For more details see this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Answer (score 0):

i think it can be resolved in your js file using these lines of code in a function that get the selected super item id as param

```
  function ShowHideItem(selectedItem)  {  
switch (selectedItem)
{
case xxx :       
 document.getElementById("Item1").style.visibility="hidden";  
 document.getElementById("Item2").style.visibility="hidden";   
break;
}
    }
```

Comment: Might be best to add a click event to each item as you render things, that way you can avoid the need for this switch.

Comment: `style.visibility="hidden"` will display the space taken by the element, `style.display="none"` will hide it completely.